# Polling network to determine whether network is reachable?

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, user-experience, reachability

I was trying to implement `ASIHTTPRequest` to download files from a server. I have an option were user can add downloads to a queue and `ASINetworkQueue` handles the file downloads one by one.

I am trying to implement a feature wherein, if the user loses their network connection, my `ASINetworkQueue` should poll for network reachability continuously.  Once connectivity is available again, the application starts downloading files from where it left off.

I am not asking for code, But I would appreciate if someone can help me with a array of hints.

---

To make my application download the file from where it left off, I am using  the `ASIHTTPRequest` method

```
[request setAllowResumeForFileDownloads:YES];
```

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Reachability APIs that apple provides illustrated in their [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code.  See link.

It allows you to receive callback when reachability changes, you can also poll reachability when appropriate, such as on applicationDidBecomeActive when if the reachability has changed when you were in the background you wouldn't have been informed.

Comment: I was looking for exactly what OP is asking for .`ASIHTTPREQUEST` also refernces reachability . Should we be calling Reachability directly ? or `ASIHTTPREQUEST` provides a way to do this by providing some layer over it.

Comment: @JavaKaBaby, Yes ASIHTTPRequest does use Reachability and as far as I can tell you can rely on it for making safe requests. My coding style is 'control freak', so I like to control as much of the workflow as I can. For example if I were writing this app, when the application is launched I would check if there were any unfinished downloads and then if there were I would check Reachability for a valid connection and if there was only then would I continue said downloads.